# Understanding a piece of jQuery code used for filtering

Tags: jquery, filter

I didn't understand this. This is used for  filtering case insensitive:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){

   return (a.textContent
        || a.innerText
        || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code could be rewritten like this a bit more verbose and maybe a bit easier to understand.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    var text;

    if (typeof a.textContent !== 'undefined') {
        text = a.textContent;
    } else if (typeof a.innerText !== 'undefined') {
        text = a.innerText;
    } else {
        text = "";
    }

    text = text.toUpperCase();

    if (text.indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
        return true; // text contains the passed parameter
    } else {
        return false; // text didn't contain passed parameter.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here we go, compiler-style:

```
(a.textContent || a.innerText || "")
```

means that the following is either executed on the String defined in a.textContent, or, if that one is not set, on a.innerText. Both usually contain the text content of a given element, which in this case is called "a". If none of those Strings are defined, an empty string is used to prevent execution time errors with the following.

```
.toUpperCase()
```

converts that string (result from the following part) to uppercase, thus removing differences between lower- and uppercase letters.

```
.indexOf( m[3].toUpperCase() )
```

indexOf() gets the position, where the given parameter string is first found within the String it's executed on. For example, `("Hello").indexOf("e")` would return 1 (remember, we start counting at 0).

the m[3] gets the third Element of an array called "m" - whatever that might be. This Element, which must be a String at this point, is then also transformed to upper case. As we are now comparing two upper case strings, the whole function becomes case insensitive.

So, `indexOf( m[3].toUpperCase() )` will return the position of "m[3]" within a.textContent or a.innerText.

The last bit, `>=0` is a logical operator.
It will, at that position, turn the whole expression to "true", if the result of the indexOf()-Call returns 0 or higher. As indexOf() returns exactly this - zero or higher - if the sought-for string is found, we effectively get a "true" if `m[3]` has been found within `a.textContent` or `a.innerText`.

And this value is returned from the function by using the leading `return` keyword.

--Lukx